# Semi-partition or pre-partition

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, terminology

For a given space $X$ the partition is usually defined as a collection of sets $E_i$ such that $E_i\cap E_j = \emptyset$ for $j\neq i$ and $X = \bigcup\limits_i E_i$.

Does anybody met the name for a collection of sets $F_i$ such that $F_i\cap F_j = \emptyset$ for $j\neq i$ but

1. $X = \overline{\bigcup\limits_i F_i}$ if $X$ is a topological space, or
2. $\mu\left(X\setminus\bigcup\limits_i F_i\right) = 0$ if $X$ is a measure space.

I guess that *semipartition* or a *pre-partition* should be the right term, but I've never met it in the literature.

Comment: Are these defintions useful in your work in some way so that you wanna know if there are any results about it or are you just wondering? Although I think it is a quite cool way of partitioning a set. =) +1

Comment: @Patrick: I just use them to describe one example - and it is crucial for me that it is not a classical partition.

Comment: As for the second case: in probability theory the term would be "partition almost everywhere".

Comment: @Hagen: Thank you, I still wonder if there is a term concerning the first case since I use both conditions.

Comment: In the topological case I’d simply call it a (pairwise) disjoint family whose union is dense in $X$; I’ve not seen any special term for it. In fact, I can remember seeing it only once: such a family figures in the proof that *almost countable paracompactness*, a property once studied at some length by M.K. Singal, is a property of *every* space.

Comment: If the sets $F_i$ were open, the system fulfilling condition 1 could perhaps be called [maximal](http://www.google.com/#q="maximal+cellular+family"+topological) [cellular family](http://www.google.com/#q="cellular+family"+topological).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Would you be interested in writing some version of your comment as an answer so that this is no longer on the unanswered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brian M. Scott wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56891/semi-partition-or-pre-partition#comment131000_56891):

> In the topological case I'd simply call it a (pairwise) disjoint family whose union is dense in $X$; I've not seen any special term for it.
>
> In fact, I can remember seeing it only once: such a family figures in the proof that *almost countable paracompactness*, a property once studied at some length by M.K. Singal, is a property of *every* space.